# Logical equivalence + Quantifiers (Universal and Existential)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a Discrete Mathematics course and we're using Rosen's book (which I hate because it seems like it makes difficult material to understand even more incomprehensible). Trouble is, I am lost when it comes to combining what I learned about logical equivalency and quantifiers.

Sample problem from homework:

Show that ∃x( P(x) v Q(x) ) and ∃xP(x) v ∃xQ(x) are logically equivalent.

What is the step by step process to answering this question?

Edit: Does anyone have a recommendation for a better textbook on Discrete Math?

Comment: As for a *different* discrete mathematics book, I would recommend Knuth's *Concrete Mathematics* (which is a blend of CONtinuous and disCRETE mathematics), but that book may be a little difficult to go through if you are having trouble with Rosen's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You are over complicating this problem.

Think about what both expressions *mean*. The "proof" that 
$$
\exists x(P(x)\lor Q(x)) \Longleftrightarrow \exists xP(x)\lor \exists xQ(x)
$$
is remarkably simple.

*Proof.* Both expressions are true precisely when at least one of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ is true for at least one value of $x$ in the universe of discourse. $\Box$

---

Of course, if you want to prove it in a different manner, then you are welcome to try, but that explanation is really all you need.

---

Here's a simple example with trivial constructions, but it may help you see *why* the two expressions are equivalent. Assume we are working with integers as the domain of discourse.

Start by constructing statements $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$.

- $P(x) : x\neq x$
- $Q(x) : x=1$

Now think about what both expressions mean.

**Expression 1:** $\exists x(P(x)\lor Q(x))$ means that there exists an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ where at least one of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ is true. Well, $x\neq x$ is *never* true for any integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we know $P(x)$ is not true. However, $Q(x)$ is true. Certainly there exists an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=1$, namely $x=1$. Okay cool. So expression 1 is true for our sample constructions of $P$ and $Q$.

**Expression 2:** $\exists xP(x)\lor \exists xQ(x)$ means that (1) there exists an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $P(x)$ is true, OR (2) there exists an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $Q(x)$ is true. Well, we just saw that $x\neq x$ is never true in $\mathbb{Z}$; thus, we can throw out $\exists xP(x)$, but what about $\exists xQ(x)$? Again, certainly there exists an $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=1$, namely $x=1$. Thus, $\exists xQ(x)$ is true, thereby making $\exists xP(x)\lor \exists xQ(x)$ a true statement.

---

Notice that Expression 1 and Expression 2 are really saying the same thing; that is, they are actually logically equivalent.

Comment: You're right. That's pretty much word for word the answer in the textbook. But how do you KNOW that? How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: @discretemathNotGenius It may be more helpful in this instance to think of how it might *not* be true. Could that be possible?

Comment: @discretemathNotGenius Can you make headway with it? Try to construct some examples.

Comment: I think I need to really understand the very basics of this question.

So ∃x(P(x)∨Q(x)) means in plain English that "there is a number x where...."

Comment: @discretemathNotGenius I just updated my answer to make everything very clear via an example. If it still does not make sense, then I am not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Hallelujer. Thank you thank you thank you. I think I am beginning to get it. I'm going to print this out and really dissect what you wrote. I appreciate your taking the time. Truly.

Comment: @discretemathNotGenius You're welcome. Don't give up on math. It takes a lot of patience. This stuff used to give me problems too. Part of the process..."growing pains" as they call them.

Answer (score -1):

$\exists{x}(P(x)\lor{Q(x)})\equiv\neg \forall{x}\neg(P(x)\lor{Q(x)})\equiv\neg \forall{x}(\neg P(x)\land\neg{Q(x)})\equiv \neg\forall{x}\neg P(x) \land \neg\forall{x}\neg{Q(x)} \equiv \exists{x}P(x)\land \exists{x}Q(x) $

Comment: The last two steps are wrong : it must end with $\lor$ ...

Comment: This just replaces the original problem with proving the same for $\forall$: $\forall x P(x) \wedge Q(x) \equiv \forall x P(x) \wedge \forall x Q(x)$...